# Adding Email Field on popup in contact form and then submit

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, popup

I am trying to make a contact form where user when clicks on submit, a popup comes up and it asks for verify email and input field for email and submit button.

So data should be passed on to popup.

I am using dialog box jquery for this. Tried making it on jsfiddle.net but i am not so sound of it.

Here is my code :

Form Code :

```
  <form action="contact-submit.php">
   First Name : <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
   Last  Name  : <input type="text" name="lastname" />
   <div class="dialog"> //used to popup
    Verify your email address <br />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: can you show what you have done so far? show in the question field

Comment: I edited the post and code added.